# How to get json data by name using python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm kinda new JSON and python and i wish to use the keys and values of JSON to compare it.

I'm getting the JSON from a webpage using requests lib.

Recently, I've done this:

```
import requests;

URL = 'https://.../update.php';
PARAMS = { 'platform':'0', 'authcode':'code', 'app':'60' };

request = requests.get( url=URL, params=PARAMS );
data = request.json( );
```

I used this loop to get the keys and values from that json:

```
for key, value in data.items( ):
    print( key, value );
```

it return JSON part like this:

```
rescode 0
desc success
config {
    "app":"14",
    "os":"2",
    "version":"6458",
    "lang":"zh-CN",
    "minimum":"5",
    "versionName":"3.16.0-6458",
    "md5":"",
    "explain":"﻿",
    "DiffUpddate":[         ]
}
```

But in Firefox using pretty print i get different result look like this:

```
{
    "rescode": 0,
    "desc": "success",
    "config": "{
        \n\t\"app\":\"14\",
        \n\t\"os\":\"2\",
        \n\t\"version\":\"6458\",
        \n\t\"lang\":\"zh-CN\",
        \n\t\"minimum\":\"5\",
        \n\t\"versionName\":\"3.16.0-6458\",
        \n\t\"md5\":\"\",
        \n\t\"explain\":\"﻿\",
        \n\t\"DiffUpddate\":[\n\t\t\n\t]\n
    }"
}
```

What I'm planing to do is:

```
if data['config']['version'] == '6458':
    print('TRUE!');
```

But everytime i get this error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the config

```
json.loads(data['config'])['version']
```

Or edit the PHP to return an associative array rather than a string for the config object

Comment: By the way, python doesn't need semicolons to end lines